# Firebird datatype mapping to c# datatypes using entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird

Specially I cant find any firebird datatype that is mapped to boolean by the entity framework (ef6).

On searching for it I found mapping tables e.g. for Oracle.

Is there a mapping table for all firebird datatypes which shows the mapped c# datatypes?

I'm using `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` and `EntityFramework.Firebird`.

Comment: Firebird currently doesn't have boolean datatype (it will be added in Firebird 3).

Comment: Thank you for the information that boolean will be added in Firebird 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SMALLINT` is mapped to `Boolean` optionally (you can also use `#BOOL#` in comments ([more info](http://blog.cincura.net/231978-seamless-support-for-boolean-and-guid-datatypes-in-firebird-and-entity-framework/)) to help EDMX designer).

You can see all the mapping for types [here](https://github.com/cincuranet/NETProvider/blob/master/NETProvider/src/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/Entity/ProviderManifest.xml).